# How to plot two functions $x^{2}+y^{2}=1$ and $xy+1=z$ in 3D in the same axes?

Tags: plotting, functions

How to plot two functions $x^{2}+y^{2}=1$ and $xy+1=z$ in 3D in the same axes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `ContourPlot3D`

```
ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + y^2 == 1 , x y + 1 == z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1,1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

While @Ulrich Neumann has provided an excellent answer, I'd like to offer some visualization alternatives for completeness.

---

1. Using **[`Plot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot3D.html)**

---

The command is

```
Plot3D[Evaluate@
  Table[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, x y + 1 == z}, {z, -1, 1, 0.25}], {x, -1, 
  1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  SwatchLegend[Range[-1, 1, 0.25], LegendLabel -> Style[z, 14, Bold]],
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y, z}), 
 ClippingStyle -> None]
```

and the plot

> [image: p1]

---

2. Using **[`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html)**

---

The command is

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@Table[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, x y + 1 == z}, {z, -1, 1, 
    0.05}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic]]
```

and you get the plot

> [image: p2]

---

3. Using **[`Animate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animate.html)**

---

The command is:

```
dat = Animate[
  Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, x y + 1 == z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 
    1}], {z, -1, 1}]
```

you can export where you saved the notebook

```
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]
Export["gif.gif", dat]
```

and your animation looks like this:

> [image: gif]